# How to print multiple components in react js?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, printing

My parent component have multiple component like below

```
    class DashboardPage extends Component {
        render() {
            const { classes } = this.props;
            return (
                <div>
                  <ReactToPrint
                      className={classes.content}
                      trigger={() => <a href="#">Print this out!</a>}
                      content={() => this.componentRef} 
                  />
                  <Card>
                    <ProfileHeader {...this.state}/>
                    <ContentLeft {...this.state}/>
                    <ContentRight {...this.state}/>
                    <ContentLeft1 {...this.state}/>
                    <ContentRight1 {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectTopic {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectContent {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectTopic1 {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectContent1 {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectTopic2 {...this.state}/>
                    <ProjectContent2 {...this.state}/>
                  </Card>
              </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

if I want to print 1 component I can use below code

`<ComponentToPrint ref={el => (this.componentRef = el)} />`

How can I use something inside card tag so I can print every component

> please help me with this im newbie

Comment: what do you mean by printing? do you want to get elements logged in console?

Comment: I want to get element in pdf for actual printing

Comment: I refer this doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print

Comment: Couldn't you do `<Card ref={el => (this.componentRef = el)}>` ?